Where can I find original statement of Hensel lifting lemma over integers modulo prime power in Kurt Hensel's publications?
Hensel lifting lemma asserts that if a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients has a root $z$ modulo a prime power $p^n$ then with the extra assumption that $f'(z)$ does not vanish modulo $p$, this root can be lifted to a root $z* $ of $f(x)$ modulo $p^{n+1}$. Finding this root is very similar to Newton’s method: $ z*=z-f(z)/f'(z)$ works. Here $1/f'(z)$ means the inverse of $f'(z)$ modulo $p$.
Where can I find the first appearance of above result in Hensel’s works?
In Hensel, Theorie der Algebraischen Zahlen, there are related results about $p$-adic integers but I was unable to locate the specific result above. I suspect that the above result is proved in a paper prior to the above book.

Not my area of expertise but I think the publication you are looking for is: K. Hensel, "Neue Grundlagen der Arithmetik."  Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, Vol. 127, 1904, pp. 51-85

The nlab page on Hensel's lemma here has links to two early publications by Hensel about this result. Since you are interested in "first appearances", it's worth noting that Gauss had some awareness of the $p$-adic lifting phenomenon in Hensel's lemma, at least in the case of lifting simple roots mod $p$: see the MSE page here.
